# Why User "system:serviceaccount" can not list some resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to add some deployments on one cluster. But

```
Error from server (Forbidden): replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "replicationcontrollers" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Error from server (Forbidden): daemonsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "daemonsets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope

Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "deployments" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope

Error from server (Forbidden): replicasets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "replicasets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope

Error from server (Forbidden): statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "statefulsets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope

Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" at the cluster scope

Error from server (Forbidden): jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" at the cluster scope
```

My svc account

```
kubectl get serviceaccount svcaccount -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: picaaaaaaaa-docker
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-21T11:39:40Z"
  labels:
    kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: post
    kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: reserved-flux-system
  name: svcaccount
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "00003700"
  uid: 88d57aav-5b87-42d0-8d1f-d20000d0be8
secrets:
- name: svcaccount-token-picaa
```

How do I fix this?
Should I crete new service account?

Comment: Did you create a Role and RoleBinding granting it the permissions it needs?